# Fetching selected Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring I want to get all the data  whose id=given by me. Can any one tell me how can I do That

```
@Override
    public Collection<Device> listDevice() {
        Collection<Device> deviceCollection=new ArrayList<>();
        Iterable<Device> deviceIterable=deviceRepository.findAll();
        for(Device d:deviceIterable){
            deviceCollection.add(d);
        }
        return deviceCollection;
}
```

This is giving me all the data But I want data having id

```
long id=device.getManufacturer_id();
```

please tell how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Repository#findAll`, use `Repository#findById(ID primaryKey)`.

Check this documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/

Comment: You're welcome @Sumeet. And feel free to check the answer if you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try SpringDao library for JDBC related operations in Spring framework. It gives lots of pre built classes for requirements like your like NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport, JdbcDaoSupport etc.

Will find host of examples of that on the net. just google it.